# .Net Core 3 EF - Order Included Array

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I am trying to return the newest result of Status from n array of statuses, but I have no idea how to implement this on an include.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Ticket>> GetTickets()
    {
        var tickets = await _context.Tickets
            .Include(c => c.Client)
            .Include(r => r.Region)
            .Include(rl => rl.RouteLink)
            .Include(e => e.Engineer)
            .Include(p => p.Priority)
            .Include(s => s.Statuses.).ThenInclude(s => s.Status)
            .Include(tcb => tcb.TicketCreatedBy)
            .Include(t => t.Team)
            .ToListAsync();
        return tickets;
    }
```

Comment: Are you wanting the `Tickets` model with only the latest `Status` object, or do you just want the resulting `Tickets` model to have the `Statuses` ordered by the `Status`?

Comment: @Matt U - The first, I want to return the complete Ticket model with the exception of only returning the latest within it for the Status object.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would help.

```
var tickets = await _context.Tickets
        .Include(c => c.Client)
        .Include(r => r.Region)
        .Include(rl => rl.RouteLink)
        .Include(e => e.Engineer)
        .Include(p => p.Priority)
        .Include(s => s.Statuses.).ThenInclude(s => s.Status)
        .Include(tcb => tcb.TicketCreatedBy)
        .Include(t => t.Team)
        .Select(x => new TicketDto
         {
            ...
            Statuses = x.Statuses.OrderByDescending(o => o.DateProperty).Take(1)
            ...
         })
        .ToListAsync();
```

but then you won't need Include directives because of the usage of `Select`